# How can parse JSon with special characters?

Tags: javascript, json

This my text in database:

```
"推奨切削条件 "
```

in PHP, i using Json_encode:
Result:

```
{"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]};
```

In javascript :

```
var strData ='{"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]}';//getData();
strData=strData.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");      
var jsonData = JSON.parse(strData)
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 56
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

[image]
How can parse JSon with special characters?

Thanks all.

Comment: Why do you have a JSON string *as string literal* inside your Javascript? How does it get there from PHP?

Comment: in PHP , i save json to file, i copy from file to js.

Comment: Well, you ain't gonna do that in the final application, are you? If you copy and paste as a string literal, you need to take care to escape specific characters (mostly backslashes) properly so it will form a proper Javascript string literal. You're dealing with issues that won't arise in your final actual usage (I presume).

Comment: Is this your actual JSON, because it appears to be valid

Comment: Yes, it is my actual.

Comment: @deceze, i must that.

Comment: You must what…?

Comment: i have to copy json to js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i have to copy json to js

I have no idea why, but okay… You don't need to deal with it as JSON string inside Javascript at all then. JSON is a *valid Javascript literal*. So just paste your JSON into your Javascript *without the quotes*:

```
var data = {"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]};
```

This is a perfectly valid Javascript object literal which requires no parsing.

If you need a valid Javascript string literal containing a JSON string, `json_encode(json_encode(...))` it twice to get:

```js
var strData = "{\"table1\":\"\\u63a8\\u5968\\u5207\\u524a\\u6761\\u4ef6 \\b\"}";
console.log(JSON.parse(strData));
```

Comment: I'm sorry , i not copy direct. I create i file js from php :  function getData() {return '{"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]}';} and i include this file to html and call function getData from my javascript.

Comment: If you need a valid Javascript string literal of a JSON string, JSON-encode it twice and the JSON encoder will take care of forming a proper Javascript string literal.

Comment: Is it $json=json_encode(json_encode(array('table1'=>$posts)));?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: it error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 3

Comment: Yeah, no, you're not treating the string properly then.

Comment: this is my json string: function getData() {return '"{\"table1\":[{\"Item\":{\"original_text\":\"\\u63a8\\u5968\\u5207\\u524a\\u6761\\u4ef6 \\b\"}}]}"';}

Comment: What `json_encode` gives you is *a valid Javascript literal*. Don't put any quotes around that or in it or anywhere near it. Copy and paste what `json_encode` gives you directly into `return ...;`, replacing "`...`".

Answer (score -1):

You can try out as,

```js
var strData ='{"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]}';

strData=strData.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");    

// Your code
// var jsonData = JSON.parse(strData);

var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(strData));

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData)));
```

Comment: jsonData  will return string, not object.

Answer (score -4):

please replace the \b to ""   strData=strData.replace("\b","");

```
<script>
    var strData ='{"table1":[{"Item":{"original_text":"\u63a8\u5968\u5207\u524a\u6761\u4ef6 \b"}}]}';
   strData=strData.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");   
   strData=strData.replace("\b","");
   document.write(strData); 
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(strData)
   document.write(jsonData);
```